# Type conversion in Sending javaScript variable to php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a javascript variable contains boolean value

```
var value=true;
alert(typeof(value)); //Output: boolean
```

I am sending this variable to a php file using ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {value:value},
    url: 'ajax.php',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

In my php code i got the value as a string

```
$value=$_POST['value'];
echo gettype($value); //Output: String
```

Why i got the value as string..?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: And why do you need it to be a boolean? PHP does the typecasting automatically. In PHP you can try to check it like `if($value==true){...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the POSTdata is sent as a string because it's not possible to send any other data types over HTTP.

Numeric data-types get guessed by PHP ("Ah this looks like a number, I'll automatically convert it!") and objects can be represented as JSON or other ways of serializing them. Booleans tend to get represented as 0/1 or "on"/"" (for checkboxes, most notably).

You'll have to manually convert values you expect to be boolean, which depends on exactly how it's being transmitted.

```
// 0 or 1
$value = !! $_POST['value'];
$value = (bool) $_POST['value'];

// 'true' or 'false'
$value = 'true' === $_POST['value'];

// 'on' or ''
$value = !! $_POST['value'];
$value = 'on' === $_POST['value'];
```